# Apply List of functions on List of columns based on different combinations

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, sapply

I have a dataframe `df` with three categorical variables `cat1`,`cat2`,`cat3` and two continuous variables `con1`,`con2`. I would like to compute list of functions `sd`,`mean` on list of columns `con1`,`con2` based on different combinations of list of columns `cat1`,`cat2`,`cat3`. I have done them explicitly subsetting all different combinations.

```
# Random generation of values for categorical data
set.seed(33)
df <- data.frame(cat1 = sample( LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE ), 
                cat2 = sample( LETTERS[3:5], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                cat3 = sample( LETTERS[2:4], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                con1 = runif(100,0,100),
                con2 = runif(100,23,45))

# Introducing null values 
df$con1[c(23,53,92)] <- NA
df$con2[c(33,46)] <- NA

results <- data.frame()
funs <- list(sd=sd, mean=mean)

# calculation of mean and sd on total observations
sapply(funs, function(x) sapply(df[,c(4,5)], x, na.rm=T))

# calculation of mean and sd on different levels of cat1 
sapply(funs, function(x) sapply(df[df$cat1=='A',c(4,5)], x, na.rm=T))
sapply(funs, function(x) sapply(df[df$cat1=='B',c(4,5)], x, na.rm=T))

# calculation of mean and sd on different levels of cat1 and cat2
sapply(funs, function(x) sapply(df[df$cat1=='A' & df$cat2=='C' ,c(4,5)], x, na.rm=T))
.
.
.
sapply(funs, function(x) sapply(df[df$cat1=='B' & df$cat2=='E' ,c(4,5)], x, na.rm=T))

# Similarly for the combinations of three cat variables cat1, cat2, cat3
```

I would like to write a function on dynamically computing the list of functions for list of columns based on different combinations. Could you please give some suggestions. Thanks !

**Edit**:
I have already got some smart suggestions using `dplyr`. It would be great if someone provides suggestions using the `apply` family functions as it will help in using them(dataframes) in the further requirements.

Comment: You could try `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(cat1, cat2, cat3) %>% summarise_each(c("sd", "mean"))` and read more about `?summarise_each`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Smart solution. I have a small question on it. When I require only to apply functions on `con1`,`con2` based on `cat1`,`cat2` it is also calculating the mean and sd of cat3. How to avoid this ? I have used `df %>% group_by(cat1, cat2) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE),sd(., na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: There are different options for selecting/unselecting specific columns, for example you could do `df %>% group_by(cat1, cat2) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE),sd(., na.rm = TRUE)), -cat3)` or `df %>% group_by(cat1, cat2) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE),sd(., na.rm = TRUE)), starts_with("con"))`. For more info, look at the special functions mentioned in `?select` from dplyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple one-line base solution:

```
> do.call(cbind, lapply(funs, function(x) aggregate(cbind(con1, con2) ~ cat1 + cat2 + cat3, data = df, FUN = x, na.rm = TRUE)))
   sd.cat1 sd.cat2 sd.cat3  sd.con1   sd.con2 mean.cat1 mean.cat2 mean.cat3 mean.con1 mean.con2
1        A       C       B       NA        NA         A         C         B  25.52641  37.40603
2        B       C       B 32.67192  6.966547         B         C         B  46.70387  34.85437
3        A       D       B 31.05224  6.530313         A         D         B  37.91553  37.13142
4        B       D       B 23.80335  6.001468         B         D         B  59.75107  30.29681
5        A       E       B 22.79285  1.526472         A         E         B  38.54742  25.23007
6        B       E       B 32.92139  2.621067         B         E         B  51.56253  29.52367
7        A       C       C 26.98661  5.710335         A         C         C  36.32045  36.42465
8        B       C       C 20.22217  8.117184         B         C         C  60.60036  34.98460
9        A       D       C 33.39273  7.367412         A         D         C  40.77786  35.03747
10       B       D       C 12.95351  8.829061         B         D         C  49.77160  33.21836
11       A       E       C 33.73433  4.689548         A         E         C  55.53135  32.38279
12       B       E       C 25.38637  9.172137         B         E         C  46.69063  31.56733
13       A       C       D 36.12545  6.323929         A         C         D  48.34187  32.36789
14       B       C       D 30.01992  7.130869         B         C         D  53.87571  33.12760
15       A       D       D 15.94151 11.756115         A         D         D  35.89909  31.76871
16       B       D       D 10.89030  6.829829         B         D         D  22.86577  32.53725
17       A       E       D 24.88410  6.108631         A         E         D  47.32549  35.22782
18       B       E       D 12.73711  8.151424         B         E         D  33.95569  36.70167
```