# performing t-test on dplyr group_by columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133492/apply-list-of-functions-on-list-of-columns-based-on-different-combinations) question, How can I incorporate `t.test` for each column(`con1`,`con2`) there based on the resulting two groups(`A`,`B`) in the new data frame i.e., `t.test`(`df$con1[df$cat1=='A']`,`df$con1[df$cat1=='B']`) and `t.test`(`df$con2[df$cat1=='A']`,`df$con2[df$cat1=='B']`)

```
# Random generation of values for categorical data
set.seed(33)
df <- data.frame(cat1 = sample( LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE ), 
                cat2 = sample( LETTERS[3:5], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                cat3 = sample( LETTERS[2:4], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                con1 = runif(100,0,100),
                con2 = runif(100,23,45))

# Introducing null values 
df$con1[c(23,53,92)] <- NA
df$con2[c(33,46)] <- NA

# List of functions 
df %>% group_by(cat1) %>% 
 summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
                     sd(., na.rm = TRUE)), 
                starts_with("con"))
```

And in this case with groups corresponding to `A`,`B` i.e., `t.test`(`df$con1[df$cat1=='A' & df$cat2=='C']`,`df$con1[df$cat1=='B' & df$cat2=='C']`), ... `t.test`(`df$con2[df$cat1=='A' & df$cat2=='E']`,`df$con2[df$cat1=='B' & df$cat2=='E']`)

```
df %>% group_by(cat1, cat2) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
                         sd(., na.rm = TRUE)), 
                    starts_with("con"))
```

Comment: In my opinion, you are better off getting the `htest` class object in a list than coercing the output into a data.frame. You can return a list of all combinations with `by(df, list(df$cat1, df$cat2), function(x) t.test(x$con1, x$con2))`. If you only want `A-C, B-C`, then you can replace the input data set with `subset(df, cat1 %in% c("A", "B") & cat2 == "C")`

Comment: @Vlo Thanks for the suggestion. I guess, my explanation confused you. I have included more details on what I am expecting, could you please have a look at the combinations now ! Thanks.

Comment: The first line already does the t-test for every combination pairwise `A-C, B-C, A-E, B-E`

Comment: @Vlo It is calculating the t-test between the two columns `con1`,`con2`, which is not required. It should be performed within the column for different groups. please have a look at the example, if it makes sense. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.  The best solution I came up with is assign the variables that distinguish the 2 samples for the t-test to a list:

```
groups<-c(a,b)
```

Next, you can use lapply and deployer:

```
t_test_summary <- lapply(groups, function(x){

t.test(filter(df, col_a== con1 & col_b ==x) %>% select(col_wanted),filter(df, col_a== con2 & col_b ==x) %>% select(col_wanted))

}
```

I have not fully adjusted it to your example, but it should get you pretty close.  In my problem, I needed to run a t-test on for 2 different samples (distinguished by col_a) for multiple time periods (loaded into the list and and inserted into the lapply to filter col_b).  Sounds almost exactly like your problem.